# Prerequisite to learn the Baum-Welch algorithm

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Eventually, I would like to learn the Baum-Welch algorithm. When I talk about mathematical prerequisites, I mean what would be the matter that I should look at and not the courses I have to take.  Could anyone have time to tell me what are the mathematical perquisites for such thing?

To describe me, I have 9 years old, and I know elementary probabilities and statistics.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to

- Review and have a solid grasp on conditional probability and joint probability Bayes rules. Be comfortable with deriving probabilities in analytical form.
- Fully understand the basic knowledge of Markov chain before checking HMM.
- Dynamic programming is the key of Baum-Welch algorithm (and many other algorithms in Markov chain and HMM). I would strongly recommend you to understand the key ideal of dynamic programming and using recursions to solve the problem.

Comment: for example, you feel comfortable to read [this tutorial](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html)